# Enable image upload tab in ckeditor

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor

Can anybody guide me how to enable the image upload tab in the ckeditor integrated with an asp.net?

Saw few links online but unable to follow. Please suggest something in simple terms.
Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit of a process, and one which I'm still working through myself, but I have got it working, so...

CKEditor itself doesn't have an uploader, so the first thing you need to do is figure out what you're going to use to do the job. I ended up choosing to use the filemanager component from FCKEditor, because there is a truly excellent walk-through for setting it up.

Walk through here: http://www.mixedwaves.com/2010/02/integrating-fckeditor-filemanager-in-ckeditor/

It is written for PHP, but it's easy enough to follow through for the .Net equivalent. One word of warning, though, you will need to get the FCKEditor.dll and install it in your bin directory, otherwise you'll get an error.